# Could we use "Creating a new BigQuery table as an event to trigger running a predefined BigQuery query"?

Tags: google-bigquery

Pub/Sub can use "a new storage file in Google Cloud Storage" as a trigger.

Could we use "Creating a new BigQuery table in a dataset, as an event to trigger running a predefined BigQuery query"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have trigger support. But you could implement something using [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) + [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).